# Non-split chain complex which is chain-homotopy equivalent to its homology sequence

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

This is exercise 1.4.4 from Weibel. Consider the homology $H_*(C)$ of chain complex $C$ as a chain complex with zero differentials. It is easy to show that if C is split, then there is a chain homotopy equivalence between $C$ and $H_*(C)$. But how to give an example in which the converse is false?

I think in the counterexample we should have that $H_n(C)$ is a direct summand of $C_n$, because of zero differentials in $H_*(C)$. I thought of something like
$$
0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow 0,
$$
where the first non-trivial arrow maps $1$ to $(2,0)$, and the second one $(1,0)$ to $1$ and $(0,1)$ to $0$. However, it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by a "split chain complex"?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, by split chain complex I mean that there is a counter-homomorphism $s_n:C_n\rightarrow C_{n+1}$, such that $d = dsd$. This is equivalent to the splitting $C_n = B_n\oplus B_{n-1}\oplus H_n$, where $B_n=\text{Im}(d_{n+1})$. Here the deal is to think about complexes for which $C_n = M_n\oplus H_n$, but $M_n$ does not split into previous and present image of differentials $d_i$-s.

Comment: How to prove this? I have proved the other way that if we have a decomposition like this  then there is $s_n: C_n \to C_{n+1}$.  I was not able to prove the existence of decomposition if we have $s_n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem in Weibel actually appears to be a mistake. If $C$ and $H_*(C)$ are homotopy equivalent, $C$ is split. I was stuck on the same thing for a while, but resolved it by asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405472/if-a-chain-complex-is-homotopy-equivalent-to-its-homology-is-it-split). See the question itself for a proof, and the accepted answer for a link to Weibel's website where the mistake is in a list of errata.